# Naming my DB tables - Suggestions?

Tags: sql-server, naming-conventions, naming

I have a couple of properties in my sql server `SLS.Customer` table which are references to other tables. I can't think of proper names for those tables. Help please :)

`Table1`: Contains the "How did you hear about us" values. (Example records: Through a friend, Advertisement, Seminar x, conference y, etc.)

`Table2`: Contains various reasons a customer refused to buy our product.

`Table3`: Contains the industry/business type a customer belongs to. (I thought of `CustomerIndustry` or just `Industry` but it sounds strange!!

`Table4`: Contains contact info of the person(s) related to a customer entity (specially if the customer is a company, rather than an individual, I need contact info of a person in charge). This is different from the tables `PartyAddress` and `PartyPhones`

Comment: Why do you care about naming conventions in this code?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your question! Why wouldn't I care?

Comment: Yalda: So naming the fields `f1`, `f2`, ... would be fine with you?  If not, why not?

Comment: @CharlesStewart Maybe I wasn't clear in the question. But those other fields are a whole other entities (and have their own separate table to hold their values)! How can I name my `PersonInCharge` entity as `f5`?

Comment: You have nine fields spread over five tables.  If I answered your qn so: "Name the fields f1 to f9, and the tables t1 to t5", I guess you would not be happy with it.  But it answers the question you have actually asked perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question is suggestion based. I just put some suggestions here.

**Table1:**

```
RefererInfo
RefererDetails
```

**Table2:**

```
backlogReasons
backlogInfo
backlogDetails
```

**Table3:**

```
CustomerCategory
CustomerBackground
```

**Table5:**

```
PersonInChargeForParty
ContactsForParty
```